# Not getting correct date from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am using following code to get a date from string but its not showing correct date

```
NSDateFormatter *saveddf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[saveddf setDateFormat:@"EEEE_MMMM dd_YYYY hh:mm a"];
[saveddf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *savedtdate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
savedtdate = [saveddf dateFromString:datestring];



Saturday_June 22_2013 11:44 AM  -- INPUT (datestring).

2013-01-05 06:14:00 +0000 This is output i am getting.(savedtdate).
```

Please tell whats wrong in my code.

Comment: and you have not defining the datestring that's why this error occured..

Comment: Try with `[saveddf setDateFormat:@"EEEE_MMMM dd_yyyy hh:mm a"];`

Comment: Did you try removing [saveddf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]]; ?

Comment: @Adithya i already tired but no reason i dont no whats wrong here

Comment: Remove this: ` = [[NSDate alloc] init]` -- totally unnecessary.

Comment: The thing that's unclear in the above is why the day of the month is returned as 01 vs 22.  Everything else is as one would expect.  The difference in time is due to the Indian timezone.  (But NSDateFormatter tends to have difficulty when provided "conflicting" input such as both day of week and day of month, even when they don't conflict.)

Comment: samo, samo, samo, samo, samo...  Boring, boring, boring, boring, boring...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it should work:

```
NSString *yourStringDate = @"Saturday_June 22_2013 11:44 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE_MMM dd_yyyy hh:mm a"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: yourStringDate];

  //Set the required date format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm"];

NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
```

Comment: can i know whats wrong with my code i am using this format "EEEE_MMMM dd_YYYY hh:mm a"  but i am getting output in another format

Comment: you pgm output is : 22-06-2013 11:44 but he want some string not get exact date....

Comment: again after changing format i am getting but i want to know whats wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter;
NSString        *dateString;

formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

Comment: not date from string i want string from date. and i had used same code